# Tikz tree: Node size and automatic alignment

Tags: tikz-trees

I am working on a tree using tikz. Is there a way to define the node size globally? If I delete the text in my tree nodes they become really small. I want to define a different size for blue, orange and red nodes. And is there a way for automatic node alignment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    fact/.style={circle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=gray, drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    state/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=orange, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    empty/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=blue, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    leaf/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=red, circular drop shadow,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
    level distance=0.5cm, growth parent anchor=south
]
\node (Fact00) [fact] {$root$}
[sibling distance=5cm]
child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
node (State00) [state] {$pp$}
    child{
    node (State09) [empty] {$$}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [empty] {$$}
    }
    child{ [sibling distance=3cm]
    node (State09) [state] {$pp$}
        child{ [sibling distance=1cm]
        node (State10) [state] {$pp$}
            child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {$leaf$}
            }
            child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {$leaf$}
            }
        }
        child{ [sibling distance=1cm]
        node (State10) [state] {$pp$}
            child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {$leaf$}
            }
            child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {$leaf$}
            }
        }
    }
}
child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
node (State00) [state] {$pp$}
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
    }
}
child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
node (State00) [state] {$pp$}
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
    }
}
child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
    node (State01) [state] {$pp$}
    child{
    node (State11) [leaf] {$leaf$}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
    }
}
;  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `minimum size` to your styles or for all nodes, as applicable. Automatic alignment etc.: either Forest or you can use the algorithmic layouts in the Ti*k*Z graph drawing libraries, which requires LuaTeX for the computations.

Comment: Please don't use `minimal` for examples as it is not suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `minimum size` to the style definitions to enforce minimum sizes. You can't get things laid out automatically using this method, although you can use styles such as `level <n>` with keys such as `sibling distance` for tree/level-wide control.

For automatic layouts, try Forest or the algorithmic graph-drawing which are part of Ti*k*Z itself. The latter requires LuaTeX and is not specific to trees, but includes a library of tree-based layout algorithms.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  fact/.style={circle, draw=none, rounded corners=1mm, fill=gray, drop shadow, text centered, anchor=north, text=white},
  state/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=orange, circular drop shadow, text centered, anchor=north, text=white, minimum size=7mm},
  empty/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=blue, circular drop shadow, text centered, anchor=north, text=white, minimum size=9mm},
  leaf/.style={circle, draw=none, fill=red, circular drop shadow, text centered, anchor=north, text=white, minimum size=5mm},
  level distance=0.5cm,
  growth parent anchor=south,
  ]
    \node (Fact00) [fact] {$root$}
    [sibling distance=5cm]
    child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
      node (State00) [state] {$pp$}
      child{
        node (State09) [empty] {$$}
      }
      child{
        node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
      }
      child{
        node (State09) [empty] {$$}
      }
      child{ [sibling distance=3cm]
        node (State09) [state] {$pp$}
        child{ [sibling distance=1cm]
          node (State10) [state] {$pp$}
          child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {$leaf$}
          }
          child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {$leaf$}
          }
        }
        child{ [sibling distance=1cm]
          node (State10) [state] {$pp$}
          child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {$leaf$}
          }
          child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {$leaf$}
          }
        }
      }
    }
    child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
      node (State00) [state] {$pp$}
      child{
        node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
      }
      child{
        node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
      }
    }
    child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
      node (State00) [state] {$pp$}
      child{
        node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
      }
      child{
        node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
      }
      child{
        node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
      }
    }
    child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
      node (State01) [state] {$pp$}
      child{
        node (State11) [leaf] {$leaf$}
      }
      child{
        node (State09) [leaf] {$leaf$}
      }
    }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: enforced minimum sizes]

Forest tries hard to place nodes automatically and generally succeeds in avoiding overlaps for the majority of trees. It is also designed to construct trees as compactly as possible (although this can be altered if spacier trees are desired).

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  colour me/.style={
    fill=#1,
    draw=#1,
  },
  for tree={
    circle,
    circular drop shadow,
    text=white,
    math content,
    edge+={draw=gray, thick},
  },
  where n children=0{% for the leaves
    colour me=red,
    minimum size=5mm,
  }{
    if level=0{% for the root
      colour me=gray,
      minimum size=6mm,
    }{
      colour me=orange,
      minimum size=2mm,
    },
  },
  delay={
    where content={}{% just the empty nodes
      colour me=blue,
      minimum size=12mm,
    }{},
  },
  [root
    [pp
      [][leaf][]
      [pp
        [pp
          [leaf][leaf]
        ]
        [pp
          [leaf][leaf]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [pp
      [leaf][leaf]
    ]
    [pp
      [leaf][leaf][leaf]
    ]
    [pp
      [leaf][leaf]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Forest tree]

Note that the larger blue nodes are automatically accommodated by spreading out the relevant parts of the tree to make room.

The colouring here utilises a base style, `colour me`, which is configured depending on place in the tree and node content according to the following rules:

- root node? -> `gray` + size specification;
- leaf node? -> `red` + size specification;
- empty node? -> `blue` + size specification;
- otherwise -> `orange` + size specification.

More fine-grained control can be achieved by applying styles to individual nodes, but this course-grained classification suffices for the tree in the question.

Comment: How can I decrease the size of the blue nodes? Is there something like `maximum size=5mm`?

Comment: @Samuel Just make the `minimum size` smaller e.g. `5mm` rather than `12mm`.

Comment: What if the tree gets to big? I like your second example and work with it now. Is there a way to decrease the overall size of a given tree. Something like `size=\textwidth`?

Comment: @Samuel Scaling the tree (as any diagram) should be a last resort. The best method depends on the details of the tree - there really isn't a general one-size-fits-all answer. Not even if you want all-one-size.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest the following changes:

- Use `minimum size` to set a minimal size of the nodes, e.g. `minimum size=7mm`.
- Use `inner sep` to reduce the empty space in the nodes, e.g. `inner sep=1pt`.
- Factor out the style elements common to all nodes, e.g.

  ```
  common/.style={circle, draw=none, text centered, anchor=north,
    minimum size=7mm, inner sep=1pt, text=white, circular drop shadow}
  ```

  and use it as in `state/.style={common, fill=orange}`.
- Don't use math mode to typeset text in italics, use `\textit` instead; e.g. `\textit{leaf}` instead of `$leaf$`.
- Use a command to format the node contents consistently; I call it `\nc` below. E.g., define

  ```
  \newcommand\nc[1]{\textit{#1}}
  ```

  and use `\nc{leaf}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows,arrows}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\nc[1]{\textit{#1}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    common/.style={circle, draw=none, text centered, anchor=north,
      minimum size=7mm, inner sep=1pt, text=white, circular drop shadow},
    fact/.style={common, fill=gray},
    state/.style={common, fill=orange},
    empty/.style={common, fill=blue},
    leaf/.style={common, fill=red},
    level distance=0.5cm, growth parent anchor=south
]
\node (Fact00) [fact] {\nc{root}}
[sibling distance=5cm]
child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
node (State00) [state] {\nc{pp}}
    child{
    node (State09) [empty] {}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [empty] {}
    }
    child{ [sibling distance=3cm]
    node (State09) [state] {\nc{pp}}
        child{ [sibling distance=1cm]
        node (State10) [state] {\nc{pp}}
            child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
            }
            child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
            }
        }
        child{ [sibling distance=1cm]
        node (State10) [state] {\nc{pp}}
            child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
            }
            child{
            node (Leaf1) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
            }
        }
    }
}
child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
node (State00) [state] {\nc{pp}}
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
    }
}
child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
node (State00) [state] {\nc{pp}}
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
    }
}
child{ [sibling distance=1.2cm]
    node (State01) [state] {\nc{pp}}
    child{
    node (State11) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
    }
    child{
    node (State09) [leaf] {\nc{leaf}}
    }
}
;  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```